# I am using Quic.Cloud But in https://gtmetrix.com/ report, It shows to "Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)". Why is this error?

Tags: wordpress, quicksort, cdn, gtmetrix

Here is the gtmetrix scan report. https://gtmetrix.com/reports/academy.evox.cc/VGQxiCOr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *advice* to use a CDN. It is not an error, not at all. Your WordPress instance is in good shape.

Content Delivery Networks make your website faster for your visitors in various places around the world, by caching your html, javascript, stylesheet, and image files locally in various data centers.

GTMetrix [explains their advice here](https://gtmetrix.com/why-use-a-cdn.html).

Unless your users complain that your site is slow, or unless your site risks being hit with a denial-of-service attach by cybercreeps, you need not act on this advice right away.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: OP said they were using a CDN: that's what QUIC.cloud is.  They were asking why GTMetrix downscores them for not using a CDN; when they actually are.  I got here because I have the same question!